# I can't start my react-app with electron app

Tags: reactjs, electron

today I wanted to advance on the development of my application but I have some problem when i want start.

I'm on Zorin OS 16 (Linux) and when I want start electron application I can't and I get this error

```
[ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGABRT
```

I have try to set "DISPLAY" with `export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:3000` but that doesn't change anything.

Anyone got the solution?

Comment: Are you using X?

Comment: I specify when i want start a simple electron app it's possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is X ?

Comment: It's an old, perhaps obsolete windowing system that was used on, among other things, Linux. Without the `DISPLAY` env set, most X applications have no idea where to send their display commands, so they quit. Newer applications tend to use the more modern conventions, so I'm surprised you're seeing this. I've only used Fedora and Ubuntu recently, so I can't speak to what Zorin uses, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Okay, I come to resolve my error, the problem was from when I'm logged on root and not my user

Comment: Worth adding that as an answer as it might help someone else.